# Full calendar touch issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using full calendar v.13.0 and trying to popup event modal on touch slots. currently Modal popup if I click using mouse but I am generating apk using cordova and in apk modal not popup on touch.

Here is my code

```
eventRender: function(e, t, a) {
    t.draggable();
    $(e).addTouch();
    if (t.attr("href")) t.attr("data-toggle", "modal"), t.attr("href", "javascript:void(0)"), t.attr("onclick", 'calendar.openModalGcal("' + encodeURI(e.title) + '","' + e.url + '");');
    else {
        if (1 == c.icons_title) {
            var o = t.find(".fc-title").text().replace(/\[(.*?)\]/gi, '<i class="$1"></i>');
            t.find(".fc-title").html(o)
        }
        var n = e.color,
            l = moment(e.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
            r = moment(e.start).format("HH:mm"),
            d = moment(e.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
            i = moment(e.end).format("HH:mm");
        if (0 == moment(e.end).isValid()) d = l, i = r;
        null !== e.end && "month" == a.name && ("H:mm" != c.timeFormat && "h:mm" != c.timeFormat || (timeformat = e.start.format("H:mm") + " - " + e.end.format("H:mm"), t.find(".fc-time").html(timeformat))), "modal" == c.version && (t.attr("data-toggle", "modal"), t.attr("href", "javascript:void(0)"), t.attr("data-id", e.original_id), t.attr("data-rep_id", e.id), t.attr("data-title", encodeURIComponent(e.title)), t.attr("data-url", encodeURIComponent(e.url)), t.attr("data-eventstart", e.start), t.attr("data-eventend", e.end), t.attr("data-color", n), t.attr("data-d_startdate", l), t.attr("data-d_starttime", r), t.attr("data-d_enddate", d), t.attr("data-d_endtime", i), t.attr("onclick", "calendar.openModal(this)"))
    }
    Object.freeze(calendar)
}
```